# Make a class that represents an average of test scores

Tags: java

Make a class that represents an average of test scores. Make the class take an unlimited number of scores and calculate the number of tests taken along with the average.

I cannot seem to be able to figure out a way to store all the test scores as well as to count the amount of tests from the given file. At the moment this code will only count one of the tests as well as only store the last number given.

[image]

This file is given by the instructor and cannot be changed

```
public class TestScoresDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestScores t1 = new TestScores("Alice");
        TestScores t2 = new TestScores("Bob");

        t1.addTestScore(50);
        t1.addTestScore(60);
        t1.addTestScore(54);
        t1.addTestScore(73);
        t1.addTestScore(88);
        t1.addTestScore(92);

        t2.addTestScore(87);
        t2.addTestScore(97);
        t2.addTestScore(37);
        t2.addTestScore(99);

        System.out.println("-- Alice --");
        System.out.println("Num tests taken: " + t1.getNumTestsTaken());
        System.out.println("Average: " + t1.getAverage());

        System.out.println("-- Bob --");
        System.out.println("Num tests taken: " + t2.getNumTestsTaken());
        System.out.println("Average: " + t2.getAverage());
    }
}
```

End of file given by instructor.
The following is what I have so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestScores {
    private String Name;
    private double TotalScore;
    private int NumScores;
    private double Earned;

    public TestScores(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public void addTestScore(double earned) {
        Earned = earned;
    }

    public int getNumTestsTaken() {

        NumScores = 0;
        while (Earned < 100.0) { 
            NumScores++;
        }
        return NumScores;
    }

    public double getAverage() {
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(Name)) {
            double sum = 0.0;
            while (Earned <100.0) {
                sum += Earned;
                TotalScore = sum / NumScores;
                break;
            }
            return TotalScore;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "_I cannot seem to be able to figure out a way to store all the test scores_" You need some sort of array, or list, or other collection.

Comment: @csmckelvey in this case, not really. they can keep a running sum and the number of test scores as they are added. they don't seem to need to produce the list once the scores are added.

Comment: You'll need a list or you can track manually with a variable. Also your methods above in TestScores are wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you have difficulty with the concepts that you are learning in your class, I suggest that you talk to other students and your instructor. You should also look more closely at your `getAverage()` method. Chose some grade values and calculate the average by hand. Then check if your method calculates the same result.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca That is certainly one solution. I'm not sure if it would be easier for a beginner to understand and write than storing a list of all the grades.

Comment: One thing that might help is to pretend that **you** are the `TestScores` class. Your friend gives you one score at a time. What do you do with those scores as your friend tells them to you? How would you manually compute the average in this scenario?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice adding numbers and incrementing a counter would be harder than learning how to use the Collection API? I mean, it's been a while since I was a beginner, but... (not trying to be belligerent, just curious)

Comment: getNumTestsTaken() will run forever when Earned < 100.0

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I only think keeping a running total is more difficult because it is another level of abstraction. Some beginners will likely understand it, but I suspect that for most storing a list is closer to how they think about doing it by hand. Of course, there is the added complication of learning the `List` API. So it is probably a toss up as to which is more difficult.

Comment: A remark on your overall code design: variable- and field-names should always start with a lowercase letter (`private String Name;` -> `private String name;`).

Comment: For the downvoters, could you explain the reason? The code provided might not be a single file, but it's still easy to notice what the problem and solutions are...

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback. This really helped me understand this better, sorry for any mistakes on how i asked or wrote out the code for you guys.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't using the variable NumScores or TotalScore correctly. Furthermore, you should use the Java naming conventions for variables so change the first letter in the name to a lowercase letter and then use capitol letters, AKA camel case. Try the following

```
public TestScores(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    numScores = 0;
    totalScore = 0.0;
}

public void addTestScore(double earned) {
    totalScore += earned; //add to the running total
    numScores++; //add to the count
}

public int getNumTestsTaken() {
    return numScores; //simply return the counter
}

public double getAverage() {
    return totalScore/numScores; //return the total scores added up divided by the count
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this worked. Thanks for the help I appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 approaches to solve this question, both have been discussed in the comments above:

1. Use a list / array / collection to store each value
2. Sum the numbers overtime when new element is added

As your requirement says that `TestScores` class cannot be changed, then it leaves 1st approach out of the possible solutions<sup>1</sup>, that makes the only one viable answer the 2nd approach.

But before writing the answer I'll rescue @Turing85's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49696077/make-a-class-that-represents-an-average-of-test-scores#comment86405418_49696077)

> A remark on your overall code design: variable- and field-names should always start with a lowercase letter (`private String Name;` -> `private String name;`).

So, your `TestScores` attributes might become:

```
private String name;
private double totalScore;
private int numScores;
private double earned;
```

This will make your program easier to read for you and all of us. Read and follow [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html).

Now let's see what your program is doing right now:

```
t1.addTestScore(50); //earned = 50
t1.addTestScore(60); //earned = 60
t1.addTestScore(54); //earned = 54
```

What you want:

```
t1.addTestScore(50); //earned = 50
t1.addTestScore(60); //earned = 110
t1.addTestScore(54); //earned = 164
```

All you have to do (after changing variable names to start with lower case letters) is:

```
public void addTestScore(double earned) {
    this.earned += earned; //This will be adding every number you send to it to the total
    this.numScores++; //This keeps track of the number of tests taken
}
```

Now `getNumTestsTaken` method might become something like:

```
public int getNumTestsTaken() {
    return numScores;
}
```

And your `getAverage` method to become something like this:

```
public double getAverage() {
    return earned / numScores; //We already know the total amount earned as it's stored in "earned" variable and the number of scores stored in "numScores" so, this becomes a simple operation
}
```

For the rest of the code, I think it's OK.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>I'm leaving the array / collection out of this answer, but making this answer a community-wiki in case someone wants to add it as well as an answer. However I already explained the reason why this is not suitable here (as per OP's requirements).</sub>